# Error if i want to create new customer account

Tags: magento2.3.3

***CREATE NEW CUSTOMER ACCOUNT***

**[Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.](http://localhost:8080/MagentoEbenezer/customer/account/create/)**

please Dear can i help me to solve this problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. localhost url change the this ip in core_config table **127.0.0.1**

> And run php bin/magento c:f

2. Or delete all directories below **var/cache**
3. DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';

Hope it will work

Thanks.